# Windows Phone 7: How to retrieve a image from a Web Browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The IE on windows phone device can save a picture into your picture hub when you select the "save picture" option after pressing and holding on the image. I wanna make the same thing happen in my application which is built on a web browser control but it seems the control wouldn't answer the "hold" gesture.

Anybody knows how to do save an image in the web browser control, or at least is there anything I can do to tell if a user is pressing on a image in the browser control so that i may use the Webclient object to retrieve the image from the remote server?

Thanks a lot!